# Vue reactivity stays after form submit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm learning Vue.js and I'm building a bucketlist app. The issue I have is when I add a new item, my input gets cleared but when I start adding a new item, the previous item also gets updated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <add-form></add-form>
  <bucketlist></bucketlist>
</div>
```

**AddForm.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>
        Add new item
    </h2>
    <form method="post" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" v-model="title">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Status</label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="status">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            status: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formSubmit(event) {
            axios.post('/add-item', this.$data)
              .then((response) => {
                  this.$eventBus.$emit('newitem', this.$data)
              })
            // this.title = '';
            event.target.reset();
        },
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Bucketlist.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="bucketlist">
    <div v-for="bucket in bucketlist" class="bucketitem">
        <h3>
            {{ bucket.title }}
        </h3>
        <input type="checkbox" :id="bucket.id"
                     :checked="bucket.status ? true : false"
                     @click="updateStatus">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            bucketlist: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateStatus(value) {
            axios.post('/update-status/'+value.target.id, this.$data);
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/bucketlist')
            .then(response => (this.bucketlist = response.data.bucketlist));

        this.$eventBus.$on('newitem', (data) => {
            this.bucketlist.push(data);
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have tried `this.title = ''` but then I get a error `Column 'title' cannot be null` when I submit my request.

Is this not the correct way to add new items and keep the reactivity from Vue?

I've made a small (and crappy) GIF to illustrate my problem.

[image]

Comment: From a logic standpoint your example looks very much like the very common Todo MVC "app", which of course there is an implementation for vue.js, e.g. have a look here and see the kind of pattern that is implemented for it: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Why the sent items are still getting mutated?**

You are emitting your whole `$data` object ... as you can see on the image bellow that the `$data` object includes a bunch of functions that are related to your data variables directly in memory(`setters`/`getters`).

[image: console.log(this.$data)]

so when you pass that object to the other component.... **the `v-model` on your input is still bidden to that data in memory** so it can still `set` or `get` it .

## **Solution :**

instead of passing the whole `$data` object just pass a literal object containing the data you want to push into that array like :

```js
formSubmit(event) {
  var obj = {
    title: this.title,
    status: this.status
  };
  axios.post('/add-item', this.$data)
    .then((response) => {
      this.$eventBus.$emit('newitem', obj)
    })
  event.target.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing the **entire** $data object to your event.

#### Why is this a problem?

Quoted from [here](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0).

> Variables that are assigned a non-primitive value are given a reference to that value. That reference points to the object’s location in memory. The variables don’t actually contain the value.

#### Breaking down the problem

```js
const arr = [];

const obj = { title: 'a title!' };

arr.push(obj);
console.log(arr) // 0: {title: "a title!"}

obj.title = 'a modified title!';
console.log(arr) // 0: {title: "a modified title!"}
```

#### Solution

**Creating a [shallow copy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/)**

Following the example above, we can do this:

```
arr.push({ ...obj });
```

Notice that if your object has nested objects(or anything that is **not a primitve value**), the shallow copy approach won't work, because you also need to take care of those nested objects.